# Populate a textbox with selected item of a dropdownlist when selectedindex is chosen

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to populate a textbox with the contents of a dropdownlist when I select the values of the ddl. My dropdownlist displays number from a database. Each number is an index which corresponds to a title. I want for the title of the selected index to appear in a textbox when its selected. I would like to use javascript.
Thanks

```
<div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <section class="card">
              <div class="card-body text-secondary">Office Id</div>
            </section>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <section class="card">
              <div class="card-body text-secondary">
                  <asp:DropDownList ID="OfficeDrop" runat="server" class="form-control"
                      DataTextField="Office_Id"></asp:DropDownList></div>
            </section>
          </div>
          </div>
<div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <section class="card">
              <div class="card-body text-secondary">Designation</div>
            </section>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <section class="card">
              <div class="card-body text-secondary">
                  <asp:TextBox ID="DesignTxt" runat="server" class="form-control"></asp:TextBox>   </div>  
            </section>
          </div>
          </div>
```

My textbox

I did not include my c# because I would like to use jquery or plain javascript to do this

Comment: You can directly use the SelectedIndex_Change() event of ddl.

Comment: In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Let us know [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and what didn't work. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Remove everything that is not relevant. Include options in your dropdown so we can see exactly what you mean.

Comment: Make sure you search too; this has probably been answered before.